# SQL Inner Join two Columns(being the minimum from the one column)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am working on a project here where I have two tables, one with expiry dates named tracking and one with inventory data named inventoryreport. I need to gather the minimum expiry date from the tracking table as well as the quantity associated with it and update the inventoryreport table. The unique identifier in each table is the SKU number. So far this is what I have, I know it is is incomplete and I have tried min() on the tracking.expirydate I would appreciate any suggestions.

```
UPDATE InventoryReport
INNER JOIN tracking ON [InventoryReport].[SKU] = [tracking].[SKU]
SET [InventoryReport].[Expiry Date]  = [tracking].[Expiry Date], 
[InventoryReport].[Quantity] = [tracking].[Quantity];
```

Comment: You have tagged your query "mysql" and then written a query using SQL Server syntax.  That is confusing.

Comment: shoot sorry, I am using access as a front end to mysql hence the syntax difference

Answer (score 0):

If there exists nothing smaller than something, then it is the minimum, or in SQL:

```
UPDATE InventoryReport AS i
INNER JOIN tracking AS t ON t.[SKU] = i.[SKU] AND NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT t2.[Expiry Date]
    FROM tracking AS t2
    WHERE t2.[SKU] = t.[SKU] AND t2.[Expiry Date] < t.[Expiry Date]
) SET i.[Expiry Date] = t.[Expiry Date], 
      i.[Quantity] = t.[Quantity]
;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this I think this is just what I am looking for. The only problem I am having now is in Access I am getting an "error in query expression ''." . It points to the second line and highlights the .[SKU] portion of [InventoryReport].[SKU]. I cannot see what could possibly be causing this.

Comment: @Clayton.n You're welcome. I'm sorry, I'm not familiar with this syntax, I couldn't find any mistake either, but unfortunately in almost any DBMS the error messages can be pretty horrible if you're unlucky and point you into the wrong direction. I'll make some edits, then you can try again.